# How do I test an https redirect in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-2.1

Recently, I came up with unit tests for checking some redirect rules of my ASP.NET Core 2.1 application:

```cs
[Fact(DisplayName = "lowercase path")]
public async Task LowercaseRedirect()
{
    var result = await this.Client.GetAsync("/BLOG/");
    Assert.EndsWith("/blog/", result.RequestMessage.RequestUri.PathAndQuery, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
}

[Fact(DisplayName = "add missing slash")]
public async Task SlashRedirect()
{
    var result = await this.Client.GetAsync("/blog");
    Assert.EndsWith("/blog/", result.RequestMessage.RequestUri.PathAndQuery, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
}
```

FYI: I am currently injecting the [`WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1?view=aspnetcore-2.1) into my test class, which I use to create my [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx).

But now I am curious how to check if the https redirect is working. Any ideas how to accomplish that? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should disable auto redirect feature of the httpclient and then test for Location value in the response header

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For `UseHttpsRedirection`, a port must be available for the middleware to redirect to HTTPS. If no port is available, redirection to HTTPS does not occur.

The HTTPS port can be specified by any of the following setting:

- HttpsRedirectionOptions.HttpsPort
- The ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT environment variable.
- In development, an HTTPS url in launchsettings.json.
- An HTTPS url configured directly on Kestrel or HttpSys.

Reference:[UseHttpsRedirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#usehttpsredirection)

To test for `UseHttpsRedirection`, specify the https port. You could follow steps below:

1. Configure `WebApplicationFactory` with `https_port`

   ```
   public class UnitTest1 : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<CoreHttps.Startup>>
   {
       private readonly WebApplicationFactory<CoreHttps.Startup> _factory;

   public UnitTest1(WebApplicationFactory<CoreHttps.Startup> factory)
   {
       _factory = factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder => builder
           .UseStartup<Startup>()
           .UseSetting("https_port", "8080")); 
   }
   ```
2. For default, the request url is `http://localhost/`, check the request url if client did not auto redirect.

   ```
   [Theory]
   [InlineData("/Home")]
   public async Task HttpsRedirectionWithoutAutoRedirect(string url)
   {
       // Arrange
       var client = _factory.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
                               {
                                   AllowAutoRedirect = false
                               });
       // Act
       var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
       // Assert
       Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.RedirectKeepVerb, response.StatusCode);
       Assert.StartsWith("http://localhost/",
           response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri);

       Assert.StartsWith("https://localhost:8080/",
           response.Headers.Location.OriginalString);
   }
   ```
3. check the request url if the request is auto redirect.

   ```
   [Theory]
   [InlineData("/Home")]
   public async Task HttpsRedirectionWithAutoRedirect(string url)
   {
       // Arrange
       var client = _factory.CreateClient();
       // Act
       var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

       // Assert
       Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
       Assert.StartsWith("https://localhost:8080/",
           response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri);
   }
   ```

Comment: I was going to ask a question about how to use HTTPS for the integration test in-memory server; your step 1 solved my problem. Thanks!